# ionic platform add android casue error in ionic2.x

Tags: ionic2

this is my ionic info ionic platform add android cause the following error

```
D:\08-sample\myApp2>ionic platform add android
Error: Failed to fetch platform android
Probably this is either a connection problem or platform spec is incorrect.
Check your connection and platform name/version/URL.
Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=connect ETIMEDOUT 93.184.216.34:8080

D:\08-sample\myApp2>ionic platforms
Installed platforms:

Available platforms:
  android ~6.1.1
  blackberry10 ~3.8.0
  browser ~4.1.0
  firefoxos ~3.6.3
  webos ~3.7.0
  windows ~4.4.0
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to check , whether ionic exists here :

```
C:\Users\yourPC\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

and you also need to set environment variables for the same, make sure your variable name , "Path" have values for npm and JDK both. Your desktop/laptop might need a restart after this process. This issue happens if u don't have required version of JDK installed. 
 u may also specify the vresion of android platform u want to add like this:

eg:- `ionic platform add android@6.0.0`
 this way should work for you.

Comment: thank you   I try to new project in win7  node_modules seems add more folders than win10, I think it's npm package cause the errror